# Eclipse Plugin to Convert Class Files to Java Source Code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, reverse-engineering, decompiling

Is there available an Eclipse plugin to decompile class files when source is not available (generate .java source code from .class files), something similar to what Resharper  does for C# in VS.NET?
Alternatively, is there a plugin which enables a friendlier view of the API of a class files than the default Eclipse view?

Comment: [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/) is good.

Comment: I use [JadClipse plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jadclipse/?source=navbar) and it works well for me.

Comment: Yes, the standalone app works fine, but I could not install properly the eclipse plugin.

Comment: I like the question, it was useful for me and the answer was also useful for me.

Comment: For those of you who are new to eclipse - the easiest way to install the plugin is through the Marketplace. You can go to Eclipse --> Help --> Eclipse Marketplace and search for the JadClipse plugin.

Comment: Is the JAD good for Windows 10 cos the site is showing only up to NT....