# How to convert .class file to .java file?

Tags: java, class, decompiling

I am trying to convert a `.class` file to `.java`.  I have only the `.class` file. I used `jad`, but I'm getting error as:

```
 The class file version is 49.0( only 45.3, 46 and 47 are supported)  JavaClassFileParseException.
```

How do I resolve this issue? Kindly provide your valuable inputs.

The Simple way to do is using: SeeMyCode

Comment: Use a newer decompiler?

Comment: See this link... This might help you...
[Eclipse Plugin to Convert Class Files to Java Source Code][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046186/eclipse-plugin-to-convert-class-files-to-java-source-code

Comment: @immibis newer decompiler? any link regarding the same

Comment: @user3497375 http://google.com/search?q=java+decompiler

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/162/open-source-java-decompiler-that-does-not-crash-on-huge-projects-understands-ad

Comment: Duplicate

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225537/convert-class-to-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use Java Decompiler http://jd.benow.ca/ in it you can open jar, or .class and it will converted to java source.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I read the .jar file. Now I am able to see .class file. Now how to convert it to .java file?

Comment: just click on the .class and it will show the java code

Comment: ya I am able to see the file. But its encoded..

Answer (score 0):

It's because you care using a lower version of Java than the one that was used for compiling the class